# How to do unit testing in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

Is there any support for unit testing in Visual Studio 2005? After googling for some time, I found out that we can do unit testing with Visual Studio Team System, but I do not have it.

I cannot install NUnit also because of some stupid rules of my organization. Does anyone knows how to do unit testing in Visual Studio?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to VS 2008, they changed their stance and included unit testing in the non Team suite level versions of the IDE.

Comment: Then I will never be able to do unit testing. My company wont buy new version and gettin NUnit installed will take atleast 1 week.

Comment: I'm with Simon then. Wait the week and get N-Unit. Waiting a week is a far cry from "cannot install." You can't make do with unit testing the old fashioned way for a week?

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use NUnit (and presumably MBUnit etc.), then you have two options: upgrade to VS2005 Team System or VS2008 Professional.  Sure, it will possibly cost money, but if challenged when presenting your case to the manager, point out that their "policy" is what's costing them the money.